# PHP array index to array associative

Tags: php, arrays

I got a array of array in PHP that look like this :

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'abc' (length=3)
      1 => string 'def' (length=3)
      2 => string 'ghi' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '01234' (length=5)
      1 => string '01234' (length=5)
      2 => string '01234' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '98765' (length=5)
      1 => string '98765' (length=5)
      2 => string '98765' (length=5)
```

Now I want the first array to be the key of a assosiative array for the rest of the parent array, **or kind** :

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'abc' => string '01234' (length=5)
      'def' => string '01234' (length=5)
      'ghi' => string '01234' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'abc' => string '98765' (length=5)
      'def' => string '98765' (length=5)
      'ghi' => string '98765' (length=5)
```

EDIT: But I can only get the first array like this to define the header :

`$header = reset($tabOfTabs);`

Comment: Have you tried something to get to your goal?

Comment: Yes I can get the first array, to define a variable that contains the "header" : `$header = reset($tabOfTabs);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this -

```
$indexes = array_shift($your_array); // pop out the first array to set the indexes

foreach($your_array as $key => $array) {
    $your_array[$key] = array_combine($indexes, $array); // combine the keys & sub-arrays
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/531809)

Comment: It works thanks but I got another tab and only the header and the first line of data have the same size, and the rest got (size - 1), I get this error and try to solve it with array_pad : `Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements `

Comment: In that case you can remove one from indexes or add an empty value to sub arrays.

Comment: Thanks I succeed by try catching the exeption and a call to `array_pop($indexes);`